# Is there a way that I can rewrite my CSS border to use color codes instead of RGB?

Tags: css

I have the following in my code that I inherited.

```
            border: 1px solid;
            border-top-color: rgb(80, 163, 200);
            border-right-color: rgb(41, 124, 180);
            border-bottom-color: rgb(8, 63, 111);
            border-left-color: rgb(41, 124, 180);
```

Is there a way that I can change this to just a normal border CSS or do I still need to specify each side?

Comment: Do you mean you want only one declaration? I don't know what a "normal border CSS" is.

Comment: Do you mean Hex Colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can write it normally

```
border: 1px solid;
border-top-color: #50A3C8;
border-right-color: #297CB4;
border-bottom-color: #083F6F;
border-left-color: #297CB4;
```

You can use the following [Tool](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm) to convert your rgb to hex values

In one line

```
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #50A3C8 #297CB4 #083F6F #297CB4
```

The syntax is Border-color: top right bottom left;

Comment: Thanks Rex, Can you convert to just one line with this?

Answer (score 1):

yes. You can use hash code. 
for example to show white color, you can use #ffffff
border : 1px solid #ffffff;
CSS for your above example,

Border-top : 1px solid #0053a3; Border-right : 1px solid #297cb4; Border-bottom : 1px solid #083f6f; Border-left : 1px solid #297cb4;

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the `Hexidecimal` colour values instead of `RGB`:

```
border-style:solid;
border-color:#0000FF;
```

There are many sources for finding the Hex values for the colours you wish to use : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this?

```
border-color: rgb(80, 163, 200) rgb(41, 124, 180) rgb(8, 63, 111) rgb(41, 124, 180);
```

Comment: You're still using RGB values

Comment: "or do I still need to specify each side?"

Comment: Still in this case don't forget the `border: 1px solid;` first otherwise no border will show.

Comment: @Paddyd, OP didn't say he wants hex.

Comment: @Sébastien, notice the property. It's `border-color`, not `border`.

Comment: @matewka "color codes **instead of rgb**" kinda says they don't want RGB - most likely alternative is hex

Comment: @matewka I never said he did. But he was looking for an alternative to RGB!

Comment: @Paddyd, you're right. I was confused since the OP mentioned it in the title and not in the question itself.

Comment: @matewka exactly so that way no border will show unless you specify `border: 1px solid;` You need it somewhere. You may think it is implied but it is not a full example as it is to replicate the Op's declarations.